# Autosuggest: Inconsistency in REST and native SDKs

Tags: here-api

We are using autosuggest feature on iOS and Android, and we want to show full address for places found during request.

It is not very good solution to make additional request for every found place to get an address.

When using [REST API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-autosuggest-brief.html) I can add property `show=details` to get address in response. For example `https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=51.5074,0.1278&limit=5&q=Wind&show=details`

But I haven't found such possibility on [native SDKs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.17/dev_guide/topics/places.html).

Is it possible to add address to autosuggest query results with native SDKs? Or should I use other API?

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS and Android SDKs the place details must be fetched in an additional request.

*com.here.android.mpa.search.AutoSuggestPlace*
Represents an AutoSuggestPlace which contains information about a suggested Place.
Note: detailed Place information is retrieved by way of the PlaceRequest returned from a call to the AutoSuggestPlace.getPlaceDetailsRequest() method.